# Customized Excerpt code doesn't working on WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, type-conversion, wordpress-theming

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this excerpt of code from wordpress

```
function excerpt($num) {

    $limit = $num+1;

    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);

    array_pop($excerpt);

    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)." <a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." ' class='".readmore."'>Continue Reading &raquo;</a>";

    echo $excerpt;

}
```

when I am using this it's showing:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant readmore - assumed 'readmore' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\learningwp\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php on line 71.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please describe what is the purpose of this code? The error is clearly point that you are trying to use a variable named $readmore, but on your code you are missing the $ sign, so it trying to treat it as constant "readmore" which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending the string before concatenating `readme`, therefore PHP presumes that it is a [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). This still works as PHP just assumes you meant the string literal "readme" as long as the constant does not really exists.

It is warning you (correctly) that this code will break in future versions of PHP.

To achieve the same behaviour without the warning - there is no need to end the string and read a constant, as long as you actually want to use the CSS class "readme" in tags class list.

Hence

```
class='".readmore."'
```

should become:

```
class='readmore'
```